# Jython classes and variable scope

Tags: swing, jython

What I want to know is, how can I create GUI elements using swing inside a Jython class so that they can be referenced from outside the class, and I can use statements like `button.setText("Hello")` on an object that was created inside another class. For example:

foo.py:

```
 from javax.swing import *
 class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        frame = JFrame("TEST")
        button = JButton("Hey")
        frame.add(button)
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        frame.setSize(300,200)
        frame.show()
```

and then I have another file called somethingelse.py:

```
from foo import *
run = Test()
```

If I were to want to change the button text by using `run.button.setText("Message")`, how could I organise the `Test()` class such that I could change the text from the second file, `somethingelse.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is throwing away the references it has to the controls, so you can't access them from anywhere - `frame` and `button` are local variables, and disappear once `__init__` returns.

You should (minimally) make them object members:

```
class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = JFrame("TEST")
        self.button = JButton("Hey")
        self.frame.add(button)
        # ...
```

You can then say:

```
from foo import *
run = Test()
run.button.setText("Message")
```